# Django - customisation doesn't work at Photologue

Tags: python, django, photologue

I've got a web app built on Django Photologue. I want to add some changes (limited access to web). I created a new application, `photologue_custom` and did other things as in example ([example](http://django-photologue.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/customising/views.html)). But I have error: "TemplateDoesNotExist at...No template names provided".

```
**urls.py at photologue_custom**

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^gallerylist/$',
CustomGalleryListView.as_view(),
name='gallery-list'),
    ]



**views.py at photologue_custom**

class CustomGalleryListView(ListView):
def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        print ("User not authenticated")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print ("User authenticated")
        return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
        paginate_by = 20

**settings.py**
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/templates',  ), ],
```

Path:

```
/home/celinaitomek/wedding-gallery/mysite -> my app

/home/celinaitomek/wedding-gallery/photologue -> photologue

/home/celinaitomek/wedding-gallery/photologue_custom/urls.py -> photologue_custom
```

Without customisation it works fine:

```
**urls.py at photologue**
url(r'^gallerylist/$',
        GalleryListView.as_view(),
        name='gallery-list'),

**views.py at photologue**
class GalleryListView(ListView):
    queryset = Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
    paginate_by = 20
```

Please, help me.

Comment: The line:

    url((r'^gallerylist/$', auth_views.login),

is strange - I am not sure that it will work. Have you tried the pagination example using exactly the example code that you link to?, i.e.:

    url(r'^gallerylist/$',

Comment: Pagination works, thanks Richard, but there is another problem - template does not exists

Comment: Problem solved.  I added a line at views.py, class CustomGalleryListView(ListView):   'template_name = 'photologue/gallery_list.html''